# How can I pull another repository and update to its head in GIT?

Tags: git

Here is the description of the problem in terms of Mercurial:

Given:

- Two repos **A** and **B**, where **B** is a fork of **A**
- The current directory is a working directory for the tip of **A**.

Needed:

- Pull in **B** and update to its most recent head **REV**.

This is what I want to do in term of Mercurial:

```
A> hg pull B
A> hg heads         # Notice the most recent head of B
A> hg update **REV**
```

How can I do it in GIT?
More concretely:

- **A** is the master branch of https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery.git
- **B** is the master branch of https://github.com/jafl/yui3-gallery.git
- I need to update to the most recent revision of **B**, when I have a local clone of **A**

I know it should be trivial, still I cannot figure it out.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add other_repo
git fetch
git merge other_repo/branch
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add a_repo a_repo_url
git fetch a_repo
git merge a_repo/branch
```